# Angular unit test for material chips with input

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

I am trying to get a unit test working for the mat-chips element, currently I'm getting an error: Can't bind to 'matChipInputFor' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. Currently the Angular Material page doesn't come with unit tests for their example. The example I used it is described on https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

How do I add that property, for example matChipInputFor, in a unit test for the given input?

The  template

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

The Controller

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatChipInputEvent} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {COMMA, ENTER} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';

export interface Fruit {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  //required for the kitchen sink form
  options: FormGroup;
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.options = fb.group({
      hideRequired: false,
      floatLabel: 'auto',
    });
  }

  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  fruits: Fruit[] = [
    {name: 'Lemon'},
    {name: 'Lime'},
    {name: 'Apple'},
  ];

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruits.push({name: value.trim()});
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
    const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Unit test (template has more elements)

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { GivenComponent } from './given.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ObserversModule } from '@angular/cdk/observers'; 
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

//Material imports
import { 
  MatCard,
  MatRadioButton,
  MatRadioGroup,
  MatIcon,
  MatChip,
  MatChipList,
  MatCheckbox,
  MatSlideToggle,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatInputModule
} from '@angular/material';

describe('GivenComponent', () => {
  let component: GivenComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GivenComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ObserversModule, 
        MatRippleModule,
        OverlayModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatInputModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        GivenComponent,
        MatCard,
        MatRadioButton,
        MatRadioGroup,
        MatIcon,
        MatChip,
        MatChipList,
        MatCheckbox,
        MatSlideToggle
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GivenComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Joeri, I think you are missing a MatChipsModule import from your TestBed Module declaration.

Comment: Yes, that was the case! Thanks, you saved my hours!

Comment: my pleasure, i'll add it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `MatChipsModule` which provides this directive.

https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api